# SonarLint plugin in Eclipse not display Error Javadoc

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, eclipse-oxygen, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm trying to create method without add comment or documentation it, I expected SonarLint would show errors based on rules, but I don't see any errors or warnings. Why?

[image]

Comment: Are those rules enabled?

Comment: i don't know how enable this rule , just i install the plugin only in eclipse from https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/

Answer (score 3):

The particular rules you're looking for are "common" rules applied at the server. You're not going to see them in SonarLint. But in general:

Out of the box, SonarLint runs with the Sonar way (default) profile. If you want additional rules applied in the IDE, you'll need to:

- set up a SonarQube instance (assuming you don't already have one)
- configure a Quality Profile to your liking
- apply it to your project
- [connect](https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/howto.html#connected-mode) your project in the IDE to the project on the server

At this point you will see (almost) all the same issues in both places.